# Collapsable open/close div not closed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code for Collapsable open/close panel in Bootstrap is opened normally but the problem when one is opened it does not close only if I open another one, I test the code in online editor its working but not working in my web application I don't know why.

```css
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e072";
  float: right;
  color: #183F66;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container col-sm-10">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  Abstract
                  </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  ...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div> <!-- .panel -->

      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                      Student Group
                  </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  ...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div> <!-- .panel -->

      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                      Contact with students
                  </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  ...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div> <!-- .panel -->
  </div> <!-- .panel-group -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: yes i include it.

Comment: yes, here's a fiddle with your code and jquery included [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vpwwgw1v/3/)

Comment: I include this but still the problem  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have updated my fiddle with your include script and it works, check if you have any errors in your console, updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vpwwgw1v/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it's happen because I include bootstrap libraries and java script twice first in Layout page and second in this page when I removed this lines it's working correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```